# Extract a value from unstructured JSON response

Tags: java, json, token

My JSON response contains the token in a strange way as marked with the red line in the picture

[image]

How we can extract it without converting it to string and parsing the text? we want to extract it as is in this JSON format

Comment: Iterate through the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this JSON to  a Map<String,Object>.
Then you can easily do a getKey() to get the strange(UUId) key, and map.get(key) will give you the value for the key.